# Hide #text in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide #text in CSS

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDQaz.jpg)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kts4s.jpg)

What kind of CSS should I write to hide this text?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community. You can include a [mcve] to your question.  Adding only an image of code is not helpful [Read Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score -1):

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:aqua;
} 

.invis:hover{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.display{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="invis"></div>
<div class="display"></div>
```

Depends, you have more options to hide something:

You have 1st:

```
visibility: hidden; 
//or
opacity: 0;
```

2nd:

```
display: none;
```

Visibilty and opacity just make it invisble, but the box model is still acting in your html, so things have paddin margin and stuff.

Display none will actually dont display the element and will hide the element in the source code

Comment: But it has no Class and how to define it with CSS?

Comment: but obviously an id?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="expirationdate_formcheck" value="true">